# Crystal reports combining and finding the sum of records

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, grouping, crystal-reports-2008

In crystal reports I have records like this:

a1 7
a1 2
a1 1
a1 5
b1 5
b1 3
b1 2

But instead I'd like it to show up as this:

a1 15
b1 10

Can this be done in Crystal reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a group on the first field; insert a summary field on the second.